# Yii2 Render view from extension

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-extension

I have Yii2 application which has a regular controller with regular action and its view trying to render a view that's part of an extension. My view is in the '`views/controllerName`' folder and I'm trying to reach a view which is in '`vendor/providerName/extensionName/views/extensionController`'. What is the right way to do that?

I'm tried the regular `render()` method with different strings like: `extensionController/extensionView`, `/extensionController/extensionView`, `//extensionController/extensionView` but I keep getting an error message that the file is not found in the main view folder which is not where I want the framework to look at first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

e.g.

```
echo $this->render('@vendor/firephp/test');
```

so in your case

```
echo $this->render('@vendor/providerName/extensionName/views/extensionController');
```